# Why is my query turning into a boolean and how do I prevent this, so I can iterate over it?

Tags: python, mysql

I've created a link in the template that points to a route which should render a page that allows the user to see the name of the person logged in, as well as all the posts they've ever made. I made the necessary queries, but it's telling me that TypeError:

> Bool is not iterable.

I tried to convert the variable into a string, but it doesn't show the information I need. I actually need access to the whole table so that I can customize what shows up on the template. In particular I need a for loop to go through all the entries in the table and list each one by the column I specify.

This is the route:

```
@app.route('/users/<id>/view')
def view_user(id):
    mysql = connectToMySQL('quotes_dash2')
    query = 'SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE user_id = %(q_id);'
    data = {
        "q_id": id
    }
    userQuotes = mysql.query_db(query, data)

    mysql2 = connectToMySQL('quotes_dash2')
    query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %(us_id);"
    data2 = {
        "us_id": session['userid']
    }
    our_user = mysql2.query_db(query2, data2)

    return render_template('view.html', userQuotes = userQuotes, ourUser = our_user)
```

And this is the template that I am trying to create (bare html):

```
<h1>{{ourUser['first_name']}} {{ourUser['last_name']}}'s Quotes</h1>


    <ul>
        {% for quote in userQuotes %}
        <li>
            {{ quote['author'] }}: {{ quote['quote_content'] }}
            <hr>
        </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I expect it so that when I click on the user's name (from another page), it will bring me to a view page that has the user's name at the top, along with all the posts that the user made (they're quotes with authors). What I'm getting instead is:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

And the traceback is focusing on:

```
return render_template('view.html', userQuotes = userQuotes, ourUser = our_user)
```

and

```
{% for quote in userQuotes %}
```

I get it that userQuotes is a bool, but I did not intend for it to be that way, and I don't know how to change it so I can iterate through the table represented by userQuotes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell since we don't know what `connectToMySQL()` is doing.

Comment: Assuming it's based on this code here... https://github.com/nicksturges/newb/blob/master/mysqlconnection.py It looks like `.query_db()` can `return False` if there's a query error. (That's not great interface design, it should really be raising an exception of its own, but that's why you're getting the error talking about bool.)

Comment: (In other words, it seems likely that your MySQL query is failing, not your template code.)

Comment: Thanks so much, Amber. I want to take another look at it. Do you see any obvious problems in the queries yourself that I can fix? It seems fine to me, but I'm also not that experienced in this.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It's working now. In case anyone else runs into this problem and is curious, the problem was that I accidentally forgot to type the letter "s" after the end parentheses in the queries. So, it should've been %(us_id)s instead of %(us_id).

Comment: Unless you provide an answer, no one's ever going to find your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's working now. In case anyone else runs into this problem and is curious, the problem was that I accidentally forgot to type the letter "s" after the end parentheses in the queries. So, it should've been %(us_id)s instead of %(us_id).